# Kubernetes DNS names, Certificates, LB Design Question

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to ask what strategy to use in Kubernetes for Ingress Controllers, DNS names, certificates and apps. Not asking for technical details but more about the modeling. I have searched for recommendations on this and struggled.

Q1: Use one OR multiple Load Balancers? When would you spin a new LB - is it based on security, traffic, something else?

Q2: Lets say I have 3 Business Units and each of them have 2 Apps, what is the best way to go about DNS names and certificates?

- Use separate certs and DNS names for every App ==> 6 Certs, 6 DNS names *(bu1app1.company.com, bu1app2.company.com,bu2app1.company.com, bu2app2.company.com,...)*
- Use a cert per BU (DNS name for each BU BUT not each App) and then use path based routing for the Apps under that BU ==> 3 Certs, 3 DNS names *(bu1.company.com/app1, bu1.company.com/app2, bu2.company.com/app1, bu2.company.com/app2,...)*
- Use a single cert for all BU (single DNS for All) and then use path based routing for every BU and app ==> 1 Cert, 1 DNS name *(k8s.company.com/bu1app1, k8s.company.com/bu1app2, k8s.company.com/bu2app1, k8s.company.com/bu2app2,...)*

Any advice is appreciated.

Jake.

Comment: This question can be transferred to Serverfault instead of closing or deleting as this is related to application architecture and requires discussion or further inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1: Use one OR multiple Load Balancers? When would you spin a new LB - is it based on security, traffic, something else?**

It depends on your application architecture, number of locations you are serving, etc. There are multiple types of load balancers available like internal load balancers, external load balancers, global load balancers, network and application load balancers etc., if your application is very big, instead of having a single machine serving your entire application you can split the application into multiple groups based on their functionality and have a load balancer configured for each group based on the traffic or hits they are receiving.

**Q2: Lets say I have 3 Business Units and each of them have 2 Apps, what is the best way to go about DNS names and certificates?**

Again it depends on the type of business each of your units is handling. If all the three units are doing the same business but targeting different audience then you can have a single DNS and a certificate. If your three units are doing distinct it’s always suggest to go with distinct dns names in order to reach the targeted consumers.

Eg: If your’s is a food delivery application and you have two units one which serves all the customers and one which serves only b2b customers, here you can have a single domain name and one sub domains namely

fooddelivery.com &
b2b.fooddelivery.com